# Class Object with Dynamic Structure

Tags: c#, json, oop

Hi Am trying to parse a json Object with Help of C# DataContractJsonSerializer And this is what json may look like

{"user_id":"121","Q1":"question 1","Q2":"question 2","Q3":"question 3"}

And Number of question can be 200- 500,
So I dont want to make a DataContract with 500 Variables to parse this Json, So I was thinking if there is a way where i can call the constructor or something for this class object with a number parameter like this if there are Q1 - Q30 in jSon

Objectparse new_object  =  new Objectparse(30);

Which will create variables Q1 to Q30 at runtime? and parse the Json

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
var json = @"{""user_id"":""121"",""Q1"":""question 1"",""Q2"":""question 2"",""Q3"":""question 3""}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic result = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(result["Q1"]);
Console.WriteLine(result["Q2"]);
...
```

and if you are using an older version of .NET than 4.0 and cannot use the `dynamic` feature you could do this:

```
var json = @"{""user_id"":""121"",""Q1"":""question 1"",""Q2"":""question 2"",""Q3"":""question 3""}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(result["Q1"]);
Console.WriteLine(result["Q2"]);
...
```

But let me point out that this is an extremely poor JSON design. The person that designed this class was probably not aware of javascript arrays:

```
{
    "user_id": "121",
    "questions": [
        {
            "key": "Q1",
            "value": "question 1"
        },
        {
            "key": "Q2",
            "value": "question 2"
        },
        {
            "key": "Q3",
            "value": "question 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which could now be serialized into a strongly typed object containing a collections of questions.

Comment: Thanks Makes sense, But I dont want to go through all the Feilds From Q1 to Q500 `Console.WriteLine(result["Q1"]);
Console.WriteLine(result["Q2"])` So i was thinking if i can get a extra variable with value Count like "Count":"30" so i just have to parse 30 objects

Comment: You have to modify the JSON object. And if you modify it then use the syntax I proposed. This way you don't need any count variable.